# SOAP UI -Passing and Testing JSON Response as Request to another JSON

Tags: json, soapui

I have 2 json rest services my condition to test them is like, I will give request to one json service which in turn give me the response which I will use as one of the json input object for 2nd json service. For Example, My json1 has given response as 221 which I will use that and frame json object like

```
{id:221,name:'test Json'}
```

and pass it over to json2 where 221 is the response from json1. Will that be possible? Can anyone please explain?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Did you even try the documentation? [Your First REST Test](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/rest-testing/) and [Top 10 Tips for the SoapUI Beginner](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/10-tips-for-the-soapui-beginner/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the Property transfer functionality in SOAPUI. Store your response in a variable (property) and pass it over with standard format ${#Variable} to next test step

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this
1st one is:

1. Use property transfer to get the value from the response and store it in the properties step.
2. Use `${Properties#propName}` to fetch the value of the property into your request where you want to use the value.

2nd approach will be to use groovy script

1. Add a groovy script step after your 1st request and Use jsonParser
   to parse the response and fetch the desired value and store it in
   properties step
2. Same as method 1's step 2.